# Sorting python dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the values are floating point numbers. I am trying to sort the dictionary in decreasing order of values and I am trying to break ties by sorting the keys in ascending order.

I implemented the following code to achieve this:

```
for key, value in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])):

    print key, value
```

**Some** of my values seem out of place.

```
2315 0.000232471518033

2823 0.000232414850716

3649 0.00023239634392

3695 0.00023239634392

3883 0.00023239634392

3479 0.00023239634392

3562 0.00023239634392

3613 0.00023239634392
```

As per the above code line starting with 3479 should be printed before the line starting with 3649.

Any ideas on what might be wrong with the way I have sorted the dictionary?
Has it got anything to do with the precision of floating point numbers?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: @grael OP is sorting by value, or rather lexicographically by `(value, key)`

Comment: What makes you think the order is *wrong*? `float`s are not *displayed* with full precision by default, hence it may *seem* that both numbers are equal, when they need not be. If you want them truncated to a certain precision, do so: `lambda x: (-round(x[1], 14), x[0])`, manually.

Comment: Print the numbers with something like print("{} {:.16f}".format(key, value)) to see more precision.

Comment: @dhke: Thanks for the suggestion. The results I was getting was because floats are not displayed with full precision by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Has it got anything to do with the precision of floating point numbers?

Yes.

```
>>> 0.0002323963439201
0.0002323963439201
>>> print 0.0002323963439201
0.00023239634392
```

Comment: No it is not about precision. Python `dict`ionaries are unordered.

Comment: @FallenAngel: You *did* see the part where `sorted()` was called, right?

Comment: @FallenAngel dictionaries aren't ordered, but the result of `sorted` is

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that part. Need one more cup of coffee.

Comment: you will get my upvote if you add what should be done to change this

Comment: @VigneshKalai: At this point what *should* be done is a matter of opinion. There are two possible ways to fix it, and there is not enough context in the question to choose between the two.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. It helped me understand the results I was getting. Just for discussion's sake, the context is that the above mentioned values are page rank scores for nodes(the keys in the dictionary are an identifier I have assigned to the different nodes). I was trying to sort the nodes in decreasing order of page rank scores to find which nodes are central to the network/graph I have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are ordering with respect to the wrong components of the dictionary. You can just do:

```
for key, value in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: (x[0]):
print key, value
```

if you want to order per key, and

```
for key, value in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1]):
print key, value
```

if you want to order per value.

Comment: Except the asker wants to sort by value descending and then by key.